# Java - How to execute user input as a method call?

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner

I want to be able to type the following into console of my IDE :

```
reverse("a b c d")
```

But currently I am only able to type

```
a b c d
```

How do I achieve this? I have tried using args[0] but I am getting an error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String sentence = sc.nextLine();
            reverse(sentence);

        }
        public static void reverse(String s){
                String [] stringArray;
                stringArray = s.split(" ");
                int counter = stringArray.length;
            for (String word : stringArray) {
                counter -=1;
                System.out.print(stringArray[counter]+" ");
            }

        }
```

Comment: according to your main method body, you are expecting a value and you are setting that value as the method parameter

Comment: do I understand correctly that you want to call the method directly? so not just passing the arguments to it?

Comment: even if you read the data as you mentioned including method name,your reverse method body will not give you expected output

Comment: the java reflection API may help you here, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: @Lino I want to be able to call the method and pass arguments into it.

Comment: you want to call the method from the console? can you give us the scenario you want?

Comment: @YCF_L When I run the application. It will ask the user for an input.
If the user enters:

reverse("I am an apple")

It will then output:

apple an am I

Comment: check my edit @LarryLiu

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem you can use some regex to get the values inside `reverse("get this")` :

```
s = s.replaceAll("reverse\\(\"(.*?)\"\\)", "$1");
```

second instead of that loop you can just use `StringBuilder::reverse` to reverse your String :

```
public static void reverse(String s) {
    s = s.replaceAll("reverse\\(\"(.*?)\"\\)", "$1");
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString());
}
```

**Input**

```
reverse("a b c d")
```

**Output**

```
d c b a
```

---

Edit

Based on your comment :

> When I run the application. It will ask the user for an input. If the
>   user enters: `reverse("I am an apple")` It will then output: 
>   `apple an am I`

In this case you have to check the name of the method, so if the String start with name `reverse` then call reverse method for example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sentence = sc.nextLine();

    if (sentence.startsWith("reverse")) {
        reverse(sentence);
    }
}

public static void reverse(String s) {
    s = s.replaceAll("reverse\\(\"(.*?)\"\\)", "$1");
    List<String> stringArray = Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s+"));
    Collections.reverse(stringArray);
    System.out.println(stringArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use the java reflection API try something like:

```
package Test;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sentence = sc.nextLine();
        Class<?> c = Class.forName("Test.Example");//your package and class
                                              //get the method to invoke
        Method  method = c.getDeclaredMethod (sentence.substring(0, sentence.indexOf("(")), String.class);
                           //get the string param
        method.invoke (c, sentence.split("\"")[1]);               
    }
    public static void reverse(String s){
        String [] stringArray;
        stringArray = s.split(" ");
        int counter = stringArray.length;
        for (String word : stringArray) {
            counter -=1;
            System.out.print(stringArray[counter]+" ");
        }
    }
    public static void doNotReverse(String s){
        System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

and you are able to type `reverse("a b c d")` or `doNotReverse("a b c d")` into console